# How to uninstall Docker completely from a Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-toolbox

I would like to remove the Docker toolbox completely from my Mac. I tried to remove Docker from the `/Applications` folder, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 119):

Start Docker. Go to the Docker Preferences from its menu bar icon. Within there is a 'Power Button' icon labeled "Reset". Click on that and then click the "Uninstall" button.

Comment: The "bomb" icon is now a "bug" icon.

Comment: Edit queue is "full"...here's a link to the relevant documentation: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#uninstall-docker-desktop

Comment: This is a non-starter if Docker isn't responding.

Comment: The "bug" icon is now a power symbol.

Comment: The "power" icon is now a "bug" again for me I guess. This app was endlessly trying to update itself. The only way to skip was to pay for Pro. No thanks!

Comment: A good start, but see answer from @mrded for more complete approach.

Answer (score 71):

To uninstall **Docker Toolbox** from Mac, first simply download the following [Docker Toolbox Uninstall Shell Script](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/uninstall.sh) to your local machine.

Use the Terminal application on your Mac (i.e. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight Search and enter keyword "Terminal") to change into the directory it was downloaded into (i.e. `cd ~/Downloads`), and then execute the file with `sudo bash uninstall.sh`.

Comment: Still application file is there.

Comment: From the command line: `curl -L -O https://github.com/docker/toolbox/raw/master/osx/uninstall.sh; sudo bash uninstall.sh`

Comment: This answer and @MatthewLeingang's script solved my "docker updating" being stuck problem on Catalina.

Comment: After running @MatthewLeingang command Docker was removed, but the very large Docker.raw file still persists in the Container/Docker/Data directory. Can I delete the Docker Directory from Containers and reclaim the space?

Comment: Form me, this did not remove docker-compose-v1, docker-credential-desktop, docker-credential-ecr-login, docker-credential-osxkeychain, and docker-index in /usr/local/bin/ that all simlink into /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/

Answer (score 58):

Remove all Docker Machine VMs:

```
docker-machine rm -f $(docker-machine ls -q);
```

Remove the application:

```
rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app
```

Remove local config:

```
rm -rf ~/.docker
```

Remove docker binaries:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
rm -r /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver*
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Remove `boot2docker.iso`:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker
```

Forget packages:

```
pkgutil --forget io.docker.pkg.docker
pkgutil --forget io.docker.pkg.dockercompose
pkgutil --forget io.docker.pkg.dockermachine
pkgutil --forget io.boot2dockeriso.pkg.boot2dockeriso
```

Comment: With the GUI stalled, this is the only thing that works!

Comment: I faced the same problem and this worked for me

Comment: This still leaves behind a gigantic ~/Library/Containers/Docker folder for me. Is it totally safe just to remove that directory?

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to remove a few other files before I could reinstall: 

`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-index`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/hub-tool`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli`
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/vpnkit`

Answer (score 39):

I realize this question is old enough that it refers to *Docker Toolbox* instead of *Docker Desktop*. My response is in regards to Docker Desktop, the latest as of this answer.

You have two ways: Command Line or GUI.

1. Via command line you execute the following command:

   $ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker --uninstall

The command line should bring up something like this:

> Docker is running, exiting... Docker uninstalled successfully. You can
>   move the Docker application to the trash.

2. With the GUI, open the Troubleshooting option and then choose Uninstall.

[image: GUI Uninstall]

Comment: When this didn't work, `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app` seemed to suffice for me, enough to reinstall so I could get the GUI back where I could then open the Troubleshooting tab and Purge data (not visible in the old screen shot here) and Reset to factory defaults.

Comment: Not my downvote, but any answer on Stack Overflow which stays up this long is likely to accrue a few stray downvotes, almost certainly by visitors who will never return here and see your comment.

Comment: Even though I couldn't get the GUI to work, somehow the CLI command you provided still launched the GUI and allowed me to uninstall. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

On my Mac M1, I could start the Docker app, but it was hanging on starting. So, this is the only thing that worked for me after deleting the Docker app (with some restarts in there):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
rm -rf ~/.docker
```

Then, you should be able to reinstall the Docker `dmg` install file.

Comment: Hat tip: https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-get-docker-working-in-macbook-pro-m1/120810/5

Comment: This solved the docker desktop startup crash I was encountering on my M1 mac.

Comment: This also fixes the kubernetes hang-up on macOS Ventura 13.6.2 with M2 chip.

Answer (score 13):

#### To uninstall Docker

This article from 2014 lists all directories and binaries in detail that you need to remove to delete the installation completely:

https://therealmarv.com/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-offical-docker-os-x-installation/

Includes boot2docker.

Of course, you probably find a lot by just typing "docker" into the finder search box. The applications themselves can be removed by deleting the `/Applications/Docker` folder.

#### To uninstall VirtualBox

1. download the *.dmg of VirtualBox for your version if you don't have it anymore
2. click on the uninstall tool in that dmg

See: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idm871

Comment: +1 for separating the references to Docker and Vbox; I use vbox still, and am thinking of moving to the beta xhyve-based docker version so this approach is merited.

Comment: +1 Thanks, worked perfect !!! I was able to uninstall the whole "Docker-Toolbox". Now I am able to install and run the new docker!

Answer (score 6):

There is an official uninstall script:

https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/blob/master/uninstall.sh

I used it successfully by entering the commands one at a time in the command line.

Answer (score 6):

It seems all the answers are dated. As of 2022, there's a section of the docs dedicated to this: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/#uninstall-docker-desktop

Quoting:

> To uninstall Docker Desktop from your Mac:
>
> - From the Docker menu, select Troubleshoot and then select Uninstall.
> - Click Uninstall to confirm your selection.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023 Aug, easiest solution for Macbook M1
`/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall`

still this will show in apps,
**open finder navigate to Application and drag it to trash**
source https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/

Comment: No such file...

Answer (score 0):

only this guide helped in my case! Hope this helps.
[enter link description here](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-docker-on-mac)

in brief:

- remove docker from /application
- remove 'com.docker.xxxxx from ~Library/application script , /cache , /container

  ```
     /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist
    /usr/local/lib/docker
    ~/.docker
    ~/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.docker.docker.plist
    ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.electron.docker-frontend.savedState
    ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker
    ~/Library/Logs/Docker Desktop
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.electron.docker-frontend.plist
    ~/Library/Cookies/com.docker.docker.binarycookies
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The Quickest and Best solution that worked for me:

1. Deleted the docker app from the Application folder and then deleted all folders by searching for "docker"
2. Then run the script

   curl -L -O https://github.com/docker/toolbox/raw/master/osx/uninstall.sh; sudo bash uninstall.sh

[image]